# Guys, need some help for starting my coding journey

Tags: c#

I'm in 11th grade and I wanted to start my coding journey. So, which courses or programs would you recommend for a person who has step a foot in the coding world.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, you need to be more specific – [see here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for details.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is pretty popular at the moment, for C# development. You will find a lot of tutorials showing how to use VSC for C# development (web pages and videos).

Later with a little bit of experience you can switch to [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/vs/community/). It is free for private developers (open or closed source projects, even commercial projects) as well as all open-source developer (even if they work for/in a company).
Because of the complexity of Visual Studio I would not recommend to use it directly from start.